# The purpose of "ihren" in " die deutsche Geschichte ihren "

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the following sentence

> Nicht in den germanischen Urwäldern hat die deutsche Geschichte ihren Ursprung [...]

what is the purpose of "ihren"?

To me it looks quite weird to have that word there, and the translator gives the same answer even if I remove "ihren" from the sentence. How the meaning of the sentence would change if I remove "ihren"?

Comment: Do not rely on automatic translators to tell you if a word is needed; they do not correct grammar and if there is a word missing they can often fill in blank using common usage patterns.

Comment: There is no reason to downvote the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not in the Germanic virgin forest, the German history has **its** origin.

The purpose of *its* is, to complete the sentence.

Whose origin? Its origin.

A more fluent English sentence structure might be:

> The German history originates not in the Germanic virgin forest.

with the verb corresponding to *origin*.

Comment: The verb is *to originate*, not *to origin*.

Comment: **Germanic** virgin forest, but **German** history.

Answer (score 0):

@user unknown is of course correct, "its" is the translation to "ihren" here, but there is more to it:

English uses the neutral "it" as a pronoun for everything not human (with a few exceptions like ships). Therefore "history" - "its".

This is not the case in German, however. German always uses the pronoun according to the grammatical gender of the noun. It is "*die* Geschichte" and hence "Geschichte" is feminine. Therefore the proper pronoun is "ihr" (her).

In English one would say:

> Here is a dog. *It* barks.

In German this would be:

> Hier ist ein Hund. *Er* bellt.

The reason is that "Hund" is masculine: "der Hund". If you want to state that the dog is female use "Hündin" (=bitch) - and the appropriate female pronoun:

> Hier ist eine Hündin. *Sie* bellt.

I will spare you an in-depth discussion about the german "Kategoriebegriff" and its meaning for the gender-discussion at this point. Only so much: "der Hund" means either a male dog OR any dog of indefinite/unknown gender - a category. A lack of knowing this can be made up for, though, by any number of special characters along with some dozens of alternative endings affixed to the noun.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, it's not so much about the gender of the pronoun (*ihr* versus *sein*), but why there is a pronoun in the first place (Quote: "[...] what is the *purpose* of 'ihren'?"). Therefore, that's more of a long comment than an answer.

Comment: Hey and what about when the thing is masculine but an object? Like Tisch. Do you still user "er" or do you use "es"? "Hier ist ein Tisch. Es/Er ist schön"

Comment: The pronoun always has to have the grammatical Gender of what it refers to. Here: 'Er'

Comment: As i have tried to explain this is a difference between English and German: in English you revert to neutral for all objects, hence: "This is a table. IT is beautiful.", whereas in German one uses grammatical genders for all sorts of objects: "Das ist ein Tisch. ER ist schön."